# how to find the rows not matched by the left join and perform some operations on top of it in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

I'm trying to delete using left join from my sql server studio and my question is how do i get the list of ids that are getting deleted as part of the left join also i would like to compare the difference between the sum from both the tables
Table A:

```
ID NAME LOC SUM
4  abc  NY   500
5  seq  CA   100
15  juv  TX   120
```

Table B:

```
ID NAME LOC SUM INFO
 5 seq   CA  90   x
18 jay   AL  94   x
15 juv   CL  190  x
```

I want to get to the number of rows that are getting removed as part of the left join and i want to see the difference in the sum

```
DELETE MYDB
FROM MYDB.A
   LEFT JOIN MYDB.B
    ON A.ID=B.ID
  WHERE  A.ID=B.ID
```

Comment: Why do you have identical `ON` and `WHERE` clauses? The `WHERE` makes the `ON` moot, and also changes the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you would be using a `LEFT JOIN` for the `JOIN`.  Your `WHERE` clause -- which is otherwise redundant -- is turning the outer join into an inner join.

I would suggest using `exists`:

```
delete from mydb.a
    where exists (select 1 from mydb.b where b.id = a.id);
```

For a count, you can use:

```
select count(*)
from mydb.a
where exists (select 1 from mydb.b where b.id = a.id);
```

Do note:  If you run these as two separate operations, the underlying data can change between the operations.

After running the delete, you can use [`@@ROWCOUNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the number of records deleted.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Gordon. How do i collaborate both these queries into one?

Comment: @kailin_mathew . . . As the last sentence suggests, you run the delete and then check `@@ROWCOUNT`.

Comment: So i can add @@ROWCOUNT at the end of the DELETE statement and it will take a count of it.?

Comment: @kailin_mathew . . . Yes.  But read the documentation.  It needs to be the statement that immediately follows the `DELETE` (because most statements reset the value).  Often, the value is assigned to a variable.